# 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis" - Error starting at line : 8 in command

Tags: sql, oracle

Can't figure out what's missing in here:

```
  CREATE TABLE "RHTIMESCEAP"."CC_CATALOG_ENVIROMENT_RISKS" (    "ENVIROMENT_RISK_ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE , 
"ACTIVITY" VARCHAR2(160 BYTE), 
"INPUT" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"ENVIROMENT_ASPECT" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"CONTROL" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
"INFLUENCE" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
"OPERATION" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
"MTTO" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
"EMERGENCY" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
"LEGAL_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"CONTROL_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"FREQUENCY_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"RESOURCE_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"HARM_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"ATMOSPHERE_CONTAMINATION_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"WATER_CONTAMINATION_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"RESIDUE_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"NOISE_CONTAMINATION_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"SOIL_CONTAMINATION_CRITERIA" NUMBER, 
"SERVICE_ID" NUMBER) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)TABLESPACE "RHTIMESCEAP_TS";
```

Could you please help me out? As I'm not missing any parenthesis at all.

Script has been exported from SQL Developer.

Comment: Which version of DB was the DDL extraction done from; and what version are you trying to run it against? That's OK [in 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fd3ac24b31d3b1fbb07864b68c25aa75) for example, but not in 12cR1 - because of `noscale`, I believe, which was added in 18c.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Remove half of the columns. Try again. Still a problem? Keep going.

Comment: Both versions are 19c.

Comment: that works for me : *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ca0658ad745f9176cf07b8c6c3d43f5)*

Comment: If there is a surrounding script then you might want to post more of it because as an individual statement it [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c586022654934fdb31c6cc721d72241d) but if there is something else in the script you are running then the error might stem from what is before (or after) in the script.